# Android Studio missing essential plugins issue

Tags: android, android-studio, jetbrains-ide

- I have successfully installed android studio but getting error on its in **Windows 10* OS*.
- Also after trying several solutions it doesn't work. I have tried:

  1.) `Delete the disabled_plugins.txt`
  2.) `Reinstall Android Studio.`
  3.) `Reinstall JDK.`
  4.) `Restart machine several times`
  5.) `Delete sdk`
- What is wrong here? Can anyone tell me?
  [image: Issue]

Answer (score 0):

Delete the disabled-plugins file usually works. Considering the steps you mentioned you've already tried, is it possible that the downloaded executable file is corrupted. When you tried to reinstall, did you used the same executable file or downloaded it again? Have you check the sha256sum for the file?

The hashes for each file can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/studio#android-studio-downloads).

Comment: But why we need to check sha256sum? I also tried with lower versions of Android Studio downloaded from official website. But it failed.

Comment: As well explained in [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/363735/what-is-a-checksum-and-why-should-you-care/): a checksum is a sequence of numbers and letters used to check data for errors. If you know the checksum of an original file, you can use a checksum utility to confirm your copy is identical.

Comment: Assuming the installation file is not corrupted, the only information available about the problem is the removal of the disabled_plugins.txt file.
I've had problems with more than one version installed and it was necessary to remove the files from both versions. I don't use Windows, but I suggest you to do a complete search (in File Explorer > This PC) for the disabled_plugins.txt file and wait to make sure you've found all the files, then delete them. Do this with Android Studio closed and launch it again.